# Github API only get pull requests that have a certain label

Tags: api, github

How do I filter the results of the following command to only give me the pull requests with a certain label: "Ready To Release" with the github api?

```
curl -u <token>-oauth-basic https://api.github.com/repos/<reponame>/<branch>/pulls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the Github Api

Just go to the following url and it will return the labels that the pull request is tagged with:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{organization_name}/{repo}/issues/{pull_request_number}/labels?access_token='{github_token})
```